# Is image of every closed set is closed set ?

Tags: general-topology

If f is continuous and bijection function of Hausdorff space into topological space. Is image of every closed set is closed set ? Thanks.

Comment: What is true is that the image of every compact set is compact. If your space is $\sigma$-compact (as $\mathbb R^n)$, then the image of every closed set is $\sigma$-compact as well.

Comment: This is true if the target space is compact: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism, http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Compact_to_Hausdorff_implies_closed

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily. For example, let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, and let $f:X\rightarrow X$ be the identity function, but give $X$ the indiscrete topology in the range. Then the domain is Hausdorff, $f$ is a continuous bijection, but the image of $[0,1]$ is not closed in the range.